# XCODE 6 / Swift - is it possible to preview admobs on un published IOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, admob, xcode6

i just finished my first ios app, and i wanted to try out some ads on the new app. but when i registered to admobs they are first asking me to search my app at the appstore,
but i havent upload it yet. is there any way to still checks ads before uploading it?

```
 GADBannerView *bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc]
              initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,
                                       self.view.frame.size.height -
                                       GAD_SIZE_320x50.height,
                                       GAD_SIZE_320x50.width,
                                       GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)];//Set Position

  bannerView.adUnitID = @"12331255421245";//Call your id

// Let the runtime know which UIViewController to restore after taking
// the user wherever the ad goes and add it to the view hierarchy.


bannerView.rootViewController = self;

[self.view addSubview:bannerView];//Your attempt to add bannerview


// Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad.

[bannerView loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
```

i saw this post, which talked about ios emulator but i havent found it, i added some code to give direction to what my meanings are. thank you   !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also add your application manually.

It's next the search button.

[image]

Comment: On the adMob website, yeah from your computer.

Comment: The problem that the guide is in objective c, how can i accomplish it using swift? is there any guide?

Comment: Your question is about how to add an app that is not published. Create a new question for how to convert this code in Swift.